# Оператор new в C# и в C++ Динамические и статические объекты

Tags: c#, c++, объекты

Решил я познакомиться с C# после C++ и удивился оператору `new`.

В C++ он выполнял роль выделения памяти из кучи и использовался для создания динамического объекта.
В C# его нужно писать постоянно для инициализации любого объекта.

То есть, как я понимаю, в C# нет динамических и статических объектов ?
И выделить память из кучи нельзя ?

Comment: Просто в C#  есть другие функции для выделения памяти из кучи и дальнейшего удаления.  malloc  и  free вместо  new и  delete

Comment: @Grundy, не согласен, это не дубликат того вопроса

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, можно пример использования `malloc` и `free` вместо `new` и `delete` в **C#**?

Comment: В С# другая модель работы с памятью, там нет возможности удалить переменную явно, только вызвав общий утилизатор. Но можно уйти в маршалинг и лов-левел, но этого обычно делать не нужно.

Comment: А что значит "статические" и "динамические" обьекты? По моему это определение надуманное. Знаю, в с++ разделяют статические и динамические массивы. Но объекты? Если по существу, то для ссылочных типов в с# оператор new делает примерно то же самое, что и в c++: выделяет память в куче и вызывает конструктор класса. Для объектов значения просто вызывает конструктор

Comment: Динамический - это тот, который находится в куче, на который мы ссылаемся, а Статический - это тот, который находится в стеке, к которому мы обращаемся напрямую, хотя возможно я это всё выдумал..
С самими вопросом я вроде бы почти разобрался